# How to find potential function for any game?

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I am studying Tim Roughgarden's lecture notes on algorithmic game theory. In [chapter 13](http://timroughgarden.org/f13/l/l13.pdf), he introduces the concept of potential function
$$\Phi(f)=\sum_{e\in E}\sum_{i=1}^{f_e}c_e(i)$$

In the context of congestion game, I understand how to calculate it. For example, given 3 edges with different cost functions $c_e(i)$ and flows $f$ along each edge (as shown in the picture below)

[image]

The potential function is simply like this (correct me if I am wrong)
$$\Phi(f)=c_1(1)+c_1(2)+c_1(3)+c_2(1)+c_2(2)+c_3(1)$$

However, when I further check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_game#A_simple_example), they mention without explanation that the potential function for the **Battle of the sexes game** with cost function $u_i(s_i, s_j) = b_i s_i + w s_i s_j$ is

$$\Phi = b_1 s_1 + b_2 s_2 + w s_1 s_2$$

How do people come up with different potential functions for different game settings?

I wonder if there is a general method for finding the potential function? Or it is just randomly trying things out and discover it?